# Django AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'field'

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to create a simple test project with one Customer model.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(name='First name', max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(name='Last name', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.first_name
```

However, when I try to enter this table in the admin console, it throws an error `AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'first_name'`. I've tried to rerun the server, but it doesn't help.
If I change the method to something else except my fields, then the problem disappears:

```
def __str__(self) -> str:
    return "1"
```

Or even if I do `return str(self.pk)` it works fine.
But I need to have `first_name` as a basic presentation of my Customer objects. So what did I miss?

Comment: Can you try to show the statement that raise the error ? Or try `return last_name`  in the `__str__` method ! And show us what happen

Comment: It produces the exact same error for every field of the class: ```AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'last_name'```

Comment: Have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` since adding this model?

Comment: Yes, I did. What I mentioned is that ```return str(self.pk)``` works fine.

Comment: My this is happening as `django.contrib.auth` User model also has the same fields `first_name` and `last_name`

Comment: @FaisalNazik surprisingly, that's the case! Thank you very much! I couldn't imagine that Django took one of the most common variable names by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The "name" parameter was the problem. If you specify it, then your variable must match it.

```
first_name = models.CharField(name='First name', max_length=20)  # <- 'name=' is the problem
```

What I actually needed is the `verbose_name` parameter. It comes first if you don't specify anything. So here is the solution:

```
first_name = models.CharField('First name', max_length=20)  # or verbose_name='First name'
```